# Por que as minhas strings não concatenam corretamente?

Tags: c

Estou querendo exibir uma informação no seguinte formato: último sobrenome/nome. Mas ele fica pulando uma linha na concatenação. Pelo menos, é o que acho que está acontecendo...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>


/*
Síntese
Objetivo: ler nome completo de uma pessoa e exibir, separado por uma barra, o último sobrenome e o primeiro nome
Entrada: Nome da pessoa
Saída: Ultimo sobrenome/Primeiro nome
*/

#define MAX_NOME 256
#define ERRO printf("\nSo pode conter letras!\n");
void apresentaNome(char * nome);
void leValidaTexto(char * msg, char * msgErro, char nome[]);
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char nome[MAX_NOME];
    leValidaTexto("Digite o nome completo:", "\nTexto invalido!\n", nome);
    apresentaNome(nome);
    return 0;
}
void leValidaTexto(char * msg, char * msgErro, char nome[]){


    int flag = 1, i=0;
    int tam;

    do{
        printf("%s", msg);
        fgets(nome, MAX_NOME, stdin);
        tam = strlen(nome)-1;

        if(tam==0){
            printf("%s", msgErro);
            flag = 0;
        }else{
            for(i=0; i < tam; i++){
                if(isdigit(nome[i])!=0){
                    ERRO
                    flag = 0;
                }else{
                    flag = 1;
                }
            }
        }

    }while(!flag);


}
void apresentaNome(char * nome){
    int i=0, j=0, k=0, p=0;
    char nomeAux[MAX_NOME], nomeAux2[MAX_NOME];
    char nomeAux3[MAX_NOME];
    char c = ' ', d = ' ';
    for(i=strlen(nome)-1; i>=0; i--){
        if(nome[i] == ' '){
            break;
        }

        c = nome[i];
        nomeAux[j] = c;
        j++;

    }
    //nomeAux[j] = '\0';
    //printf("%s", nomeAux);
    /*
    for(k=strlen(nomeAux)-1;k>=0;k--){
        d = nomeAux[k];
        nomeAux2[p] = d;
        p++;
    }
    */

    strrev(nomeAux);
    for(i=0; i < strlen(nome)-1; i++){
        while(nome[i]!= ' '){
            //printf("%c", nome[i]);
            nomeAux3[i] =nome[i];
            break;
        }
    }


    strcat(nomeAux, "/");
    printf("%s\n", strcat(nomeAux, nomeAux3));

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom, eu não entendi muito bem esse problema eu refiz totalmente ele pegando as ideias, bom ele não aceita números nem espaços, para facilitar na hora de mostrar os nomes, eu armazenei em uma matriz de caracteres e mostrei o primeiro e ultimo nome, qualquer dúvida pergunte.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int verifica(char *frase);
void mostraNaTela(char *frase);
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   char nome[20];
   printf("Digite seu nome completo\n");
   scanf(" %[^\n]", nome);
   if(verifica(nome))printf("ERRO\n\n\n");
   else mostraNaTela(nome);

    return 0;
}

int verifica(char *frase)
{
   int i;
   for(i = 0; i < strlen(frase); i++)
   {
       if(!isalnum(frase[i]) && frase[i] != ' ')
       {
          return 1;
       }
       else if(frase[i] >= '0' && frase[i] <= '9')
       {
          return 1;
       }
   }
    return 0;
}


void mostraNaTela(char *frase)
{
   char nomes[30][30];
   char *ptr;
   int cont = 0;
   ptr = strtok(frase, " ");
   while(ptr != NULL)
   {
      strcpy(nomes[cont++], ptr);
      ptr = strtok(NULL, " ");
   }
    printf("%s\\%s\n", nomes[0], nomes[cont - 1]);
}
```

Comment: Era basicamente isso, Rafael. A única coisa que saiu diferente foi a saída. Primeiro nome/último sobrenome; o problema pedia último sobrenome/primeiro nome. Entendeu? Eu tentei fazer sem usar ponteiro e outras funções apenas para treinar a minha lógica, que não é das melhores.

Comment: Só não entendi porque essa pergunta recebeu tantas avaliações negativas. Enfim, valeu aí, cara!

Comment: Por nada, a respeito da negativação da perguntar não foi muito bem explicado, dá próxima vez explique melhor.